# Accumulate values of a list

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list with that each object has two fields:

- Date as DateTime
- Estimated as double.

I have some values like this:

- 01/01/2019 2
- 01/02/2019 3
- 01/03/2019 4

... and so.

I need to generate another list, same format, but accumulating the Estimated field, date by date. So the result must be:

- 01/01/2019 2
- 01/02/2019 5 (2+3)
- 01/03/2019 9 (5+4) ... and so.

Right now, I'm calculating it in a foreach statement

```
        for (int iI = 0; iI < SData.TotalDays; iI++)
        {
           DateTime oCurrent = SData.ProjectStart.AddDays(iI);
           oRet.Add(new GraphData(oCurrent, GetProperEstimation(oCurrent)));
        }
```

Then, I can execute a Linq Sum for all the dates prior or equal to the current date:

```
  private static double GetProperEstimation(DateTime pDate)
  {
     return Data.Where(x => x.Date.Date <= pDate.Date).Sum(x => x.Estimated);
  }
```

It works. But the problem is that is ABSLOUTELLY slow, taking more than 1 minute for a 271 element list.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide the full dataset please.

Comment: The full dataset is a MS Project file with 271 elements. Is not the example enough? Do you need any other example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Simple yet effective.

```
var i = 0;

var result = myList.Select(x => new MyObject
{
     Date = x.Date, 
     Estimated = i = i + x.Estimated
}).ToList();
```

Edit : try in this way

```
.Select(x => new GraphData(x.Date, i = i + x.Estimated))
```

Comment: Tying. I'll let you know. Thanks

Comment: When I change MYOBJECT to GRAPHDATA, my object type, says: "There is no argument given that correspond to the formal parameter 'pDate' of GraphData(DateTime pDate, double pEstimated). Any clues?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Update your question so that I can see what you are doing

Comment: I changed var i = 0;

var result = myList.Select(x => new MyObject
{
     Date = x.Date, 
     Estimated = i = i + x.Estimated
}).ToList(); to var i = 0;

var result = GraphInfoList.Select(x => new GraphData
{
     Date = x.Date, 
     Estimated = i = i + x.Estimated
}).ToList(); and had that error (MyObject in your example to GraphData, my object)

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you so much @Simonare!

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly job of [MoreLinq.Scan](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#scan)

```
var newModels = list.Scan((x, y) => new MyModel(y.Date, x.Estimated + y.Estimated));
```

New models will have the values you want.

---

in `(x, y)`, `x` is the previous item and `y` is the current item in the enumeration.

---

Why your query is slow?

because `Where` will iterate your collection from the beginning every time you call it. so number of operations grow exponentially `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = ((n^2)/2  + n/2)`.

Comment: Thanks M. I will try it as a last resource. I don't want right now to install another library if I can reach the solution over standard .Net framework. Your explanation o the iteration rocks! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple LINQ-like extension method that accumulates values. This version is generalized to allow different input and output types:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<TOut> Accumulate<TIn, TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> source, Func<TIn,double> getFunction, Func<TIn,double,TOut> createFunction)
    {
        double accumulator = 0;

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            accumulator += getFunction(item);
            yield return createFunction(item, accumulator);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2018,1,1), Estimated = 1 },
        new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2018,1,2), Estimated = 2 },
        new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2018,1,3), Estimated = 3 },
        new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2018,1,4), Estimated = 4 },
        new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2018,1,5), Estimated = 5 }
    };
    var accumulatedList = list.Accumulate
    ( 
        (item)      => item.Estimated,                    //Given an item, get the value to be summed
        (item, sum) => new { Item = item, Sum = sum }     //Given an item and the sum, create an output element
    );
    foreach (var item in accumulatedList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1}", item.Item.Date, item.Sum);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
2018-01-01 1
2018-01-02 3
2018-01-03 6
2018-01-04 10
2018-01-05 15
```

This approach will only require one iteration over the set so should perform much better than a series of sums.

[Link to DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qexyvj)

Comment: This looks the ticket (pun intended). however what about dates that dont exist, was that one of the requirements ? Also adding the last accumulation in (last+Current) format maybe a requirement too

Comment: If we assume that any missing dates have an `Estimated` value of 0, it should not affect the totals, although the output won't have rows for the missing dates.

Comment: As the data is from a MS Project, there is no way (I think) of missing one date between Project Start and Finish. I'm taking in count Saturdays and Sundays and even Holidays if are declared in the .mpp file. But good observation though.

Comment: You know. You were right. I've opened a MPP that wasn't mine, and some dates had no data. Everything because of your comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that what you said is real what you need hehehe

Algorithm

```
Create a list or array of values based in the original values ordered date asc
sumValues=0;
foreach (var x in collection){
  sumValues+= x.Estimated; //this will accumulate all the past values and present value
  oRet.Add(x.date, sumValues);
}
```

The first step (order the values) is the most important. For each will be very fast.
see [sort](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sort)

Comment: I'm doing a graphic of te advance (or the need of advance) on a MS Project. So I need to accumulate over the life of the project. This algorithm work too, and is faster than mine. Obrigado pelo teu esforço! Tenha bom dia